# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ajaxsample/update_agenda (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My controller

```
public function update_agenda() {
                $id= $this->input->post('did');
                $this->load->model('agenda_model');
                $data = array (
                                'nama' => $this->input->post('dnama'),
                                'keterangan' => $this->input->post('dketer') );
                                $this->agenda_model->update($id,$data);

            }
```

and this is my script, i think problem  is come from this script

```
function saveUpdate(){
         var data = {};
         $("input:checkbox[name=checklist]:checked").each(function(){
             id_data = $(this).val();
             data['did'] = $(this).val();
             data['dnama'] = $("#nama_"+id_data);
             data['dketer'] = $("#ket_"+id_data);
             updateData(data);
         }); }
```

next script..
any solution?? i am confused where my mistake is. . .

```
    function updateData(data){

    var data = {};  
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo site_url('ajaxsample/update_agenda');?>",
                data :{data :data},
                success:function(html){
                $('ajaxsample/update_agenda').html(html);
                }   
        });
```

Comment: comment this line //var data = {};

Comment: in $.ajax change data : data

Comment: i did and stiil get error like this : uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: check in function updateData body console.log( data ) properly get key and value. 
function updateData(data){ console.log(data)

Comment: this will give you object[HTML] data['dnama'] = $("#nama_"+id_data) are you try to send value or object here ?    and its must be id or class here $('ajaxsample/update_agenda').html(html); correct way $('#id').html(); $('.class').html();

Answer (score 0):

Try this, fix some script;)

```
function saveUpdate(){
     var data = {};
     $("input:checkbox[name=checklist]:checked").each(function(){
         id_data = $(this).val();
         data.did = $(this).val();
         data.dnama = $("#nama_"+id_data);
         data.dketer = $("#ket_"+id_data);
         updateData(data);
     }); }
```

The key of js object can fetch by a **Full Stop(.)**